# Performing mTLS for a Go HTTP API running in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, ssl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Currently have a Go HTTP API using the `github.com/gin-gonic/gin` library set up to perform mTLS, like so:

```
router := gin.New()
router.GET("/ping", handlers.GinHandler{GC: globalConf, H: handler.Ping}.Handle())

// I'm checking errors but just for simplicity it's ommitted
caCert, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("ca.crt")
caCertPool, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    ClientCAs:  caCertPool,
    ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
}

server := &http.Server{
    Addr:      ":" + "8443",
    TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    Handler:   router,
}

server.ListenAndServeTLS("ssl.crt", "ssl.key")
```

It seems I need to use something like `github.com/apex/gateway` for compatibility with AWS Lambda, but there's only a `ListenAndServe` function, rather than a `ListenAndServeTLS` like with the `net/http` package.

Is it possible to perform mTLS like this, inside an AWS Lambda function?

Or does this need to be rewritten to perform the mTLS inside an API Gateway instead? If so, is it possible to forward the certificate to the Go app/Lambda function for checking the CN?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to perform mTLS like this, inside an AWS Lambda
> function?

No it's not possible. The TLS connection is terminated by API gateway, which then invokes your Lambda function via the AWS API. The Lambda function never has the network connection from the incoming request, so there's no way to perform mTLS inside the Lambda function.

> Or does this need to be rewritten to perform the mTLS inside an API
> Gateway instead? If so, is it possible to forward the certificate to
> the Go app/Lambda function for checking the CN?

Yes, the mTLS feature has to be implemented at API Gateway. I suggest following [this official guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-mutual-tls-authentication-for-amazon-api-gateway/).

Comment: Ah I see - and is it possible to send the certificate or at least the CN to the Lambda from the API Gateway once it's verified the client certificate?

Comment: The client certificate can be passed to a Lambda Authorizer (see the "Additional authorization capabilities" section at the link I posted). I believe that could add values to the `context` that get passed to the target Lambda function.